# path of wp-content directory when we are on some plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, paths

I am in a hypothetical plugins root folder. Now I want the path of the `wp-content` directory.

I need its path in some functions. Please guide me.

I tried this, but this doesn't seems to work:

```
$plugin_dir = ABSPATH . 'wp-content';
```

[image]

Comment: `wp-content` might not even exist. You can customize every child directory and set it to some custom path. The real question here is _why_ you want that directory. :)

Comment: Please explain that under what scenario this may be true "might not even exist"? wp-content, wp-admin, wp-includes → I think these are definite directories?

Comment: You can give every subdirectory a separate path outside of the WP installation, and then just [set `wp-content` to be equal with the installation root](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#moving-wp-content-folder). Still, why do you need that path?

Comment: Hi there @fuxia, Thank you so much I was not aware of that, but I think that this is a high-level thing. Organizations that are handling huge websites, in order to increase website security they change those directory paths.

Comment: Answer: I am a learner was trying to back up my folder recursively w/o help of any paid plugin. I  was trying to use a backup library on Github. Mostly for learning sake + also save my cost on backups by using paid plugins.

Comment: Okay. If it is only for your own sites, you can go with that. :) The constant `WP_CONTENT_DIR` should give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks, Can you also tell me if someone has changed the wp-content path Is there a way to get it programmatically? The path should be within the WP installation. Thanks. If possible you can write an answer too.